# ¿Como ignoro las mayúsculas y minúsculas en el logueo de laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Mi login lo tengo hecho con `make: auth` de `laravel`, el problema que tengo es que el usuario indica:

Usuario: pablocontreras

y en la `db` esta registrado "pabloContreras" (con la 'C' en mayúscula) y dice que "Estas credenciales no coinciden con nuestros registros". Supongo que el `sql` que utiliza para la consulta de la `db` no diferencia en la `db`. Lo valido a la hora de registrar un usuario con el `ilike` pero no tengo ni la mas mínima idea de donde puedo modificar el `sql` de la consulta para ingresar a mi app.

De antemano gracias.

## Actualización 1:

@Shaz en su comentario dice:

> Para poder reemplazar la parte de la consulta debes cambiar el user provider especificado en config/auth.php. El método encargado de realizar la búsqueda en la base de datos es retrieveByCredentials() en el ...UserProvider correspondiente, el cual sea probablemente eloquent en tu caso (según lo que tengas configurado en auth.php

#### Mi archivo `config/auth.php`:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
],
```

#### Mi archivo `EloquentUserProvider.php` -> metodo `retrieveByCredentials()`.

**Original:**

```
public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
{
    if (empty($credentials)) {
        return;
    }

    // First we will add each credential element to the query as a where clause.
    // Then we can execute the query and, if we found a user, return it in a
    // Eloquent User "model" that will be utilized by the Guard instances.
    $query = $this->createModel()->newQuery();

    foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
        if (! Str::contains($key, 'password')) {
            $query->where($key, $value);
        }
    }

    return $query->first();
}
```

**(Editado y funcional):**

```
public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
{
    if (empty($credentials)) {
        return;
    }
    $query = $this->createModel()->newQuery();

    foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
        if (! Str::contains($key, 'password')) {
                $query->where($key, 'ilike', $value);
                // Agregado el 'ilike' para que.
                // ignore las mayúsculas y minúsculas.
                // en los campos distintos de 'password'.
        }
    }

    return $query->first();
}
```

## Actualización 2:

 Intentando de agregar un nuevo `UserProvider`.

archivo **PropioUserProvider.php** ubicado en la carpeta: `App\Auth`.

```
model = $model;
        $this->hasher = $hasher;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a user by their unique identifier.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $identifier
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function retrieveById($identifier)
    {
        return $this->createModel()->newQuery()->find($identifier);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a user by their unique identifier and "remember me" token.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $identifier
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function retrieveByToken($identifier, $token)
    {
        $model = $this->createModel();

        return $model->newQuery()
            ->where($model->getAuthIdentifierName(), $identifier)
            ->where($model->getRememberTokenName(), $token)
            ->first();
    }

    /**
     * Update the "remember me" token for the given user in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function updateRememberToken(UserContract $user, $token)
    {
        $user->setRememberToken($token);

        $user->save();
    } 

    /**
     * Retrieve a user by the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {
        if (empty($credentials)) {
            return;
        }

        // First we will add each credential element to the query as a where clause.
        // Then we can execute the query and, if we found a user, return it in a
        // Eloquent User "model" that will be utilized by the Guard instances.
        $query = $this->createModel()->newQuery();

        foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
            if (! Str::contains($key, 'password')) {
                $query->where($key, 'ilike', $value);
            }
        }

        return $query->first();
    }

    /**
     * Validate a user against the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
        $plain = $credentials['password'];

        return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
    }

    /**
     * Create a new instance of the model.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
     */
    public function createModel()
    {
        $class = '\\'.ltrim($this->model, '\\');

        return new $class;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the hasher implementation.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher
     */
    public function getHasher()
    {
        return $this->hasher;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the hasher implementation.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher  $hasher
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setHasher(HasherContract $hasher)
    {
        $this->hasher = $hasher;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the name of the Eloquent user model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getModel()
    {
        return $this->model;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the name of the Eloquent user model.
     *
     * @param  string  $model
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setModel($model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

No elimino funciones porque no se en que me puedan influir.

archivo **PropioAuthProvider.php** ubicado en la carpeta: `App\Providers`.

```
    namespace App\Providers;

    use App\Auth\PropioUserProvider;
    use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

    class PropioAuthProvider extends ServiceProvider 
    {

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

        $this->app['auth']->extend('propio',function() {
            return new PropioUserProvider();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
    }
```

archivo **config/app.php** (registro).

```
App\Providers\PropioAuthProvider::class,
```

valor del driver en el archivo **config/auth.php**.

```
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'propio',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: ¿Qué usas MySQL? Si es así puedes declarar la columna `usuario` como **case insensitive** directamente en la tabla (ver https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) En PHPMyAdmin puedes poner cualquier columna de la tabla como tal, cambiando sus propiedades (es la propiedad que termina siempre por _ci, ejemplo: `utf8_spanish_ci`.  Si no quieres hacer esto puedes usar `uppper` o `lower` en el select, pasando el criterio convertido a mayúsculas o minúsculas según el caso. Ejemplo: `select * from users where upper(first_name) = 'FRED';`

Comment: @A.Cedano utilizo PostgreSQL

Comment: @A.Cedano donde se encuentra el `sql` de la validación de credenciales para iniciar sesión en laravel (hecho make:auth).

Comment: Eso no lo sé, no uso Laravel.

Comment: @A.Cedano ok gracias de igual manera :D

Comment: Para poder reemplazar la parte de la consulta debes cambiar el user provider especificado en config/auth.php. El método encargado de realizar la búsqueda en la base de datos es `retrieveByCredentials()` en el ...UserProvider correspondiente, el cual sea probablemente eloquent en tu caso (según lo que tengas configurado en auth.php

Comment: @Shaz hermano, solucionado con la sugerencia que tu me diste. Gracias. ¿Puedes formalizar tu respuesta para darte la aprobación de la misma?.

Comment: Asumo que creaste tu user provider, algo como "CustomUserProvider"?

Comment: jeje no, edite el original :/ (Siento que he metido la pata). ¿Como hago uno nuevo?

Comment: Nunca edites NADA que esté dentro de la carpeta vendor, ya redacto la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Para crear un nuevo UserProvider hay varios pasos:

1. Crear el UserProvider como tal, digamos que se llamará PropioUserProvider, el cual crearemos en `App/Auth`, este archivo básicamente contiene lo mismo que EloquentUserProvider pero con tus modificaciones, incluso podría extenderlo:

   ```
   namespace App\Auth;

   use ...

   class PropioUserProvider implements UserProvider {
       // código de EloquentUserProvider con tus modificaciones
   }
   ```
2. Crear un AuthProvider:

   ```
   namespace App\Providers;

   use App\Auth\PropioUserProvider;
   use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

   class PropioAuthProvider extends ServiceProvider 
   {

   /**
    * Bootstrap the application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function boot()
   {

       $this->app['auth']->extend('propio',function() {
           return new PropioUserProvider();
       });
   }

   /**
    * Register the application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function register()
   {
       //
   }
   }
   ```
3. Registrar el AuthProvider en config/app.php:

   ```
   'App\Providers\PropioAuthProvider',
   ```
4. Cambiar el driver respectivo de `'eloquent'` a `'propio'` en config/auth.php
5. Cerrar las sesiones actuales.

Comment: Gracias hermano por la respuesta. La estoy intentando implementar y me envia el siguiente error: Authentication user provider [propio] is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer que al registrar los usuarios antes de agregarlos utilice algo así como:

```
strtolower(Input::get('username'))
```

Aunque esto sólo funcionaría para nuevos registros y no para tu caso exacto.

Comment: hermano, exactamente como tu dices "no para tu caso exacto" :/ lo que busco es modificar el `sql` del login.